# Would like to run multiple instances of the same Perl script but with only one instance of an argument

Tags: perl

So I realize that I can run multiple instance of the same Perl script.  But let's say every instance of that Perl script gets passed an argument, i.e. 
`perl batch.pl userid=3`

Is there a way to check if there's already an instance of that script running with the same userid and therefore not run another instance for that userid?

Thanks

Comment: Use any of the same methods used to make sure only one script runs, but include the userid in the name of the locked resources

Answer (score 0):

Shell command to get PID of instance with userid=N:
`ps wax | grep 'batch.pl' | grep "userid=N" | grep -v grep | perl -l12 -ane 'print $F[0]'`

Comment: I would be wary of using the process list - it's all too easy to have namespace clashes that cause the lock to 'trigger'.